# Listview, with two textviews and a imageview

Tags: android, listview

i want to make a programm, with a listview.
On the left side should be a image in the center a textview and on the right another textview.

I realised a listview with a image and ONE text, but i can t add a second textview...

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

You simply use a Custom Adapter combined with your own row layout as discussed here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

If you want more specifics, please include the code that you have so far and I can make more suggestions!

Comment: Glad to help!  Btw, welcome to Stack Overflow :)  Please be sure to always mark the best answer to your questions with a checkmark.